# how to set gragle cmd output encode correctly?

Tags: java, gradle

my problem is not file encoding ,but how to make gradle display
the output correctly.

there is an obvious error in the app.code, the method

outxxx doesn't exist in System

and the app.java code is as following

`app.java`

```
public class App {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.outxxx.println();
    }
}
```

gradle version:5.6.4

build.gradle

```
plugins {

    id 'java'


    id 'application'
}

repositories {

    jcenter()
}

dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.4'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

application {

    mainClassName = 'demo.App'
}
```

```
gradle install

> Task :compileJava FAILED
D:\code\demo\src\main\java\demo\App.java:18: 閿欒: 鎵句笉鍒扮鍙?

                                                                            System.outxxx.println();
              ^
  绗﹀彿:   鍙橀噺 outxxx
  浣嶇疆: 绫?System

1 涓敊璇?
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

BTW, if i created the project with mvn ,everything works.

Comment: To clarify, the problem is that the caret ^ does not point to the correct column of the System.outxxx.println code in the line above?

Comment: no, the message from gradle is not in utf-8 encoding,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a workaround , i set my win10 system encoding to  utf-8

```
cmd>gradle build


> Task :compileJava FAILED
D:\code\demo\src\main\java\demo\App.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        System.outxxx.println();
              ^
  symbol:   variable outxxx
  location: class System
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```